# JOIN'ing by 3 tables and retrieving field based on content of those tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Kind of hard to explain, so I'll map it out. Given these four tables: `houses`, `landlord_houses`, `company` and `tenant`, I need to find all the houses that have signed up in the last 14 days and get some information about them.

Previously I've done this with a very simple `select` query from the `houses` table. But now I need to get the letting agent of the house to display on a report. The problem is, the letting agent can be in any one of 3 locations: in the `company` table, the `houses` table or in the `tenant` table. I've come up with this query so far:

```
select distinct h.id as id,
    h.address1 as address1,
    h.town as town,
    h.postcode as postcode,
    h.valid_from as valid_from,
    h.valid_to as valid_to,
    (CASE WHEN c.name IS NOT NULL THEN c.name || ' (MS)'
      WHEN h.letting_agent IS NOT NULL THEN h.letting_agent
      WHEN t.id IS NOT NULL THEN t.letting_agent
      ELSE 'Unknown (Not set yet)' END) AS agent
from houses h
left join landlord_houses lh on lh.house_id = h.id
left join company c on c.id = lh.company_id
left join tenant t on t.house_id = h.id
where h.deleted IS FALSE
and h.archived IS FALSE
and h.sign_up_complete IS TRUE
and h.completed > NOW() - '14 days'::INTERVAL
order by h.id
```

This kind of works, however I'm getting results back that have an empty `agent` field even though it's meant to say "Unknown (Not set yet)". I'm also getting duplicate houses returned even though I've used `distinct h.id`. I think this is because there are multiple letting agents for these houses in the company, houses and tenant tables.

What needs to be changed in the query to get this to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Distinct only makes it so that each tuple(row) is unique, not each individual value in the tuple. I have never tried psql but perhaps the language supports the coalesce() function? It returns the first non null value. For example coalesce(c.name,h.letting_Agent,t.letting_agent,'Unknown (Not set yet)')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That case statement looks a little wonky. You may be returning multiple values. Try this:

```
COALESCE(c.name, h.letting_agent, t.letting_agent, 'Unknown (Not set yet)') as Agent
```

This checks c.name. If it is null, move to the next argument and do the same.

Everything else in the query looks fine and this does work in postgresql.

Comment: Just tried that, gave me exactly the same output as the CASE function and I still have empty agent fields and duplicate houses. Neater, but not quite there!

Comment: So a house may have multiple letting agents? Maybe try incorporating "SELECT c.name from c limit 1" into the coalesce

Comment: A house can have one letting agent, however it may be defined in different ways. A company could own a house so the letting agent would be the company name (stored in the `company` table), or when the tenants sign up they could all put in different values for the letting agent (for example "Mr White", "Mr. White", "mr white") (stored in the `tenant` table)... I basically need to get it as a preference, first from the company table and and if it's not there from the houses table, and then from one of the tenants of the house. If I can't get a result from all 3 then display Unknown.

Comment: Yeah that's what the Coalesce function does. it checks each argument from left to right and uses the first value that isn't NULL. If they are all NULL, it uses 'Unknown'

Comment: Maybe remove distinct and group by h.id instead. Also make sure that your agent fields allow NULLs and are set to `NULL` when empty rather than `''` or something